# ¿Duda sobre instancias en django?

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Tengo una duda sobre `django`, mi pregunta es que es exactamente esto?:

```
<class 'messenger.models.Thread_messages'>
```

Lo recibo de una señal, pero no es un objeto o instancia ya que ya recibo una instancia en la señal, podría obtener todas las instancias del modelo con el, de la siguiente manera (y funciona):

```
x = <class 'messenger.models.Thread_messages'>
x.objects.all()
```

Pero que es exactamente? ***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Comment: Es un tipo de dato, te dice que es una clase del tipo 'messenger.models.Thread_messages' o sea, dentro de tu paquete messenger en el archivo models hay un modelo llamado `Thread_messages`. Funciona porque esa es la forma en la que Python representa las clases en string, es cuando le das print, pero no es una instancia, es la clase, por eso puedes hacer `x.objects.all`

Comment: Mmmm entiendo, muchas gracias por tu comentario!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<class 'messenger.models.Thread_messages'>
```

Es la representación en String de la clase `Thread_messages` dentro del módulo `models` de la carpeta `messenger`.
Puedes ejecutar la query que indicas porque estás invocando a la clase.